# Why my Ubuntu doesn't update anymore?

Tags: apt, updates, 19.04, do-release-upgrade, 19.10

One of my Ubuntu has been interrupted in the middle of a `do-release-upgrade -d` from `19.04` to `19.10`, because of network problems.

The network problems (only related to Ubuntu updates, the network is fine) continued after some days, so I've tried:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/*.bin
sudo apt update
```

but it doesn't recreate the cache - again, because of the network problems:

```
Err:1 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 90.147.160.70 80]
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Err:3 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 90.147.160.72 80]
Err:4 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports InRelease            
  Connection failed [IP: 90.147.160.73 80]
Err:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease                      
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/eoan/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 90.147.160.70 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/eoan-security/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/eoan-updates/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 90.147.160.72 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/eoan-backports/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 90.147.160.73 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/eoan/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

My `/etc/apt/sources.list` contains:

```
deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu eoan partner
```

Now the system (which is fully working, for now) it's clearly in a dirty state.

What could I try to fix the situation? What would you do? Installing/fixing from an ISO could be an option?

Thanks in advance!

NOTE: the few Q&A on the subject are VERY old (eg. Ubuntu 11) and all suggest the steps I've already tried, so please don't close this as a duplicate, it's not.

Comment: The problem is with the update `it` mirror, or you have no internet connection.

Comment: If you have a connection, switch to another mirror.

Comment: I have a connection, I've tried manually to point **sources.list** to `de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/` for the eoan-updates but nothing changed. Did you mean this with _switch to another mirror_, or doing it through the UI?

Comment: You can do it using UI. The problem is that the system can't connect to the update servers. `Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]`

Comment: Ok, I can't even browse to `ubuntu.com`. This also happens from my coworkers computers. We can ping it and also telnet it on port 80, but we can't reach it with a browser, not by name nor by ip: `https://91.189.90.59/`. I can open it from my smartphone, though. What the heck is going on??? ISP problem?

Comment: I've attached a 4G Modem and the updates are working. I'll answer the question when I'll discover what is causing ubuntu.com to be unreachable from our computers. Thanks for your help @Pilot6

Comment: This must be related to you provider

Comment: I guess so. It also caused our corporate firewall to run on very high CPU usage... we restarted it and everything has come back to normality. Thank you again, feel free to answer with "it's the network, nothing else" and I'll happily accept it. In the end, that's the answer